# Vue 3 doesn't update component UI on props change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I want my child component to be updated once props were changed. But it doesn't happens:

```html
    // App.vue
    <template>
      <div id="app">
        <Foo :foo="foo" />
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script setup>
      import Foo from '@/components/Foo.vue'
    
      const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 }
    
      //Updating the value of the passed constant each 0.5 seconds
      setInterval(() => {
        foo.a += 1
        foo.b += 1
      }, 500)
    </script>
```

Child component:

```html
    // Foo.vue
    <template>
      <div>
        <div>Value A: {{ foo.a }}</div>
        <div>Value B: {{ foo.b }}</div>
      </div>
    </template>
    
    <script setup>
      const props = defineProps({ foo: { a: 0, b: 0 } })
    </script>
```

If I put `console.log` in `Foo.vue` I can see the value is changing, but can't see those changes in the ui.

**I have a guess**: Not sure, but maybe instead of `const foo = { a: 1, b: 2 }` should be `const foo = reactive({ a: 1, b: 2 })`?
Seems to be working.
But I wonder – is this a best practice? Because in the previous Vue that wasn't needed.
And anyway would be nice to sure that changes are tracked on the `Foo.vue` side, instead of checking all the usages of that component.

---

P.S. I'm pretty sure that this question was asked before, but it's hard to find an answer due to overlapping with the previous version of vue.

Comment: Variables need to have hooked up event listener. So application know need to change DOM elements. Previous version didn't need that because the whole `data() {}` function was returning one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use ref or reactive if you want variables to be reactive

[Check out this link to find out more.](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/reactivity-fundamentals.html)

In your case, here's how to do it

```js
      import {ref} from 'vue'
      import Foo from './Foo.vue'
    
      const foo = ref({ a: 1, b: 2 })
    
      //Updating the value of the passed constant each 0.5 seconds
      setInterval(() => {
        foo.value.a += 1
        foo.value.b += 1
      }, 500)
```

[Playground example](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Comment: First of all thank you. So and if I use `Foo.vue` in a 1000 placec, I have to check every single use to make sure it's wrapped with `ref()`? Is that the only way?

Comment: If you are using composition API  yes you need to wrap your variables with ref if you want them to be reactive however you still can use Option-Api  like Vue 2. [example](https://cutt.ly/xCk0bVy)